# Prolog -how to implement a nested function in prolog?

Tags: prolog

I need to write rules below:

Write the rules for a predicate take(L,N,L1), which succeeds if list L1 contains the
first N elements of list L, in the same order. The following queries show examples of using this predicate:

```
?- take([5,1,2,7], 3, L1).
L1 = [5,1,2]
?- take([5,1,2,7], 10, L1).
L1 = [5,1,2,7]
```

My idea is to delete the first number of two list any time until L1 is empty.
I am also thinking that I can use car([X|_], X) to delete the last number each time until the first list ==the second list. I already wrote the length(L,Len), but I don't know how to do next...

My code is:

```
take(L,X,[]).(I know it miss something, but I don't know how to do...)
take(H|L,N,H|L1):- take(L,X,L1), N is X-1.
```

=========================Update=================================================
Thank you 1638891!
Right now, the code is

```
    take(L,0,[]).
    take([H|L],N,[H|L1]):- take(L,X,L1), N is X+1.
```

But it doesn't work in the second case, which is

```
   ?- take([5,1,2,7], 10, L1).
   L1 = [5,1,2,7]
```

I tried to add

```
    take([],X,[])->!.
```

But it pop up "ERROR: is/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@user1638891 forgot to swap the subtraction, and to cover the case when you are requested more elements than available:

```
take(_,0,[]).
take([],_,[]).
take([H|L],N,[H|L1]) :- N > 0, X is N-1, take(L,X,L1).
```

Comment: This answer isn't a nested function, though nested functions could be implemented [using copy_term/2](https://gist.github.com/jarble/8f8f80fa60b089d551efb0c6a74be45b/edit).

Answer (score 0):

You actually want to write X is N - 1.

```
take(L,0,[]).
take([H|L],N,[H|L1]):- take(L,X,L1), X is N-1.
```

As a general rule try to read your rules aloud. The first rule you wrote reads as "Empty list is the list with the first X elements in L." But it should have been "Empty list is the list with the first 0 elements in L" as a base case.

Comment: thank you so much! By the way it should be N is X+1... haha, it works!